# Re-adding an interface to a node in OpenNMS

Tags: opennms

Our OpenNMS was having an issue with "too many open files" and high CPU, and in the midst of the poor responsiveness decided to delete both IP interfaces from one of my nodes. Now that node has no interfaces in OpenNMS at all.

I've tried re-scanning the node but OpenNMS doesn't pick anything up. Does anyone know how to re-add the interface to the node? I'd rather not delete and re-add the node as that will remove all past history for that server.

I'm using a very old OpenNMS, version 16.0.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your node as no interfaces at all, there is nothing to rescan, as OpenNMS has to have at least one interface available. It will start with that interface and attempt to access the SNMP ipAddrTable to discover more.

You have a couple of options:

1) If the node is provisiond (i.e. exists in a requisition) you can simply edit that requisition and add an interface back. Synchronize it should be back to normal.

2) If not, you'll need to rediscover the node. Make a note of the nodeid of the original node. When the new node is discovered, you can copy all of the files from `$OPENNMS_HOME/share/rrd/snmp/[old nodeid]` to `$OPENNMS_HOME/share/rrd/snmp/[new nodeid]`and that should preserve your data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My node has interfaces, but OpenNMS won't pick them up. The node was added via the "Add interface for scanning" so there's no user-defined requisition for it. I've rediscovered the node (same way as before) and it has a new node ID.

Comment: So you have two nodes with the same IPs? That can cause issues with scanning.

If you have a node, a valid IP address, and SNMP enabled and discovered on the node, you should get all the IP interfaces present in the ipAddrTable.

Comment: Well the "old" node ID has no IP interfaces anymore, so although the node is called by the IP address nothing is recorded for it. The "new" node has the correct DNS name and IP interfaces.